# Default value for parameters can only be null

Tags: php

I am building a DI factory and seem to be getting this error:

> Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in your code on line 70

Which is this line:

```
public function get(
        $foo, bool $func = false, array $params = array()
    ) {
```

It seems that if I remove the `bool` before the `$func` paramater, it works.

Although, how can I hint a type `array` but not a type `boolean`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whar PHP Version are you using? In PHP < 7 there is no typehint for boolean values. So the interpreter assumes `bool` is a classname

Comment: 5.6 I believe? That maybe the exact issue then @l-x

Comment: Some reference for @l-x's comment: [Function arguments - Valid types](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types) (Check `Minimum PHP version` column). And if your php version is really 5.6, you can see that `array` type hint is available since `5.1.0`

Comment: Appreciated, I'll just have to remove the hint type - I only use them for better practice anyway @FirstOne